# Android app crashing RejectedExecutionException

Tags: android, firebase, crash

I recently released the app, for all version its working fine for me. but after release on the play store, I am getting a lot of crash report with the following exception I don't have any idea where and why it's crashing.

it's happening only on OS `8.0 & 8.1`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6577)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6129)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6039)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1764)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6940)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2078)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:843)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1389)
  at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init> (FirebaseCrash.java:22)
  at com.google.firebase.crash.component.zza.create (zza.java:3)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0 (ComponentRuntime.java:66)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.a (ComponentRuntime.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get (Lazy.java:53)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents (ComponentRuntime.java:155)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis (FirebaseApp.java:779)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:369)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:332)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:316)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate (FirebaseInitProvider.java:53)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1927)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1902)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo (FirebaseInitProvider.java:47)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6574)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6129)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6039)
```

Comment: I got the same issue. Did you find any solution to fix this?